# Persistent setTimeout calls in Spotify occasionally freeze UI for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, spotify

I've been been working on an animated Spotify app and have run into problems with it stuttering. After attempting to pare down animation code as much as possible and still encountering stuttering, I removed everything but the setTimeout function. Watching the Timeline in the debugger confirmed that [stuttering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSqWU.png) persisted.

To test the problem, I wrote the following snippet of code and ran it in Spotify and chrome:

```
var delta;
var newTime;
var oldTime = new Date().getTime();
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
function updateFrame() {
    newTime = new Date().getTime();
    delta = newTime - oldTime;
    if (delta>500 ) {
        console.log(delta + " @ " + Math.round((newTime-startTime)/1000) + " seconds");
    }
    oldTime = newTime;
    setTimeout("updateFrame()",50);
}
```

In spotify, typical outputs look like this:

```
 2168 @ 14 seconds
 2150 @ 51 seconds
 2151 @ 111 seconds
 2166 @ 171 seconds
 2174 @ 231 seconds
 2194 @ 291 seconds
 2181 @ 351 seconds
 2259 @ 411 seconds
 2216 @ 471 seconds
```

During those two seconds, the entire Spotify UI is totally unresponsive while music keeps playing and keystrokes are recorded. Using setInterval, different setTimeout intervals, and changing the location of setTimeout in the update function don't seem to have any effect.

In chrome, nothing is logged until the tab becomes inactive:

```
 1002 @ 9 seconds 
 1001 @ 10 seconds 
 1000 @ 11 seconds 
 1001 @ 12 seconds 
 1003 @ 13 seconds 
 1000 @ 14 seconds 
 1006 @ 15 seconds
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem - I feel like I'm doing something wrong because done of the other apps I've used freeze Spotify. This might be because they don't include persistent setTimeout calls, but I'm not sure how to create animation without them.

Comment: You might try using `requestAnimationFrame`. A quick google search should turn up some examples.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing that me towards that - not sure how I missed it before. Unfortunately, webkitRequestAnimationFrame still freezes spotify. I'm going to try uninstalling and testing on other computers when later today.

Comment: Are you certain it is your app that causes the problem, rather than some other issue? I also experience intermittent freezing in the Spotify client (in general, not a specific app) and I think it may be related to my ant-virus software (but at work I cannot switch it off to check).

Comment: Actually, I can't repeat the freezing outside of the app I'm developing, so possibly I have the same issue as you. For me, the freezing is new since I last updated the Spotify client. For reference, I'm running Windows7.

Comment: I've reinstalled Spotify on Windows 7 and on a MacBook Pro. Both produced similar error logs as the ones in the original question - two second stutters in Spotify and none in chrome until the tab times out. I think this is a new issue - I made a metronome app back in May that didn't stutter. 

Now that I'm paying attention the problem, it seems like the freezing occurs even without any apps running, but it is harder to test without running a program and notice without an animation playing.

Comment: After more testing, I agree the problem is not confined to apps, but also occurs in the main client.